# how to download ftp file in GZ format using .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, ftp, binary

When I successfully download a file from FTP in .gz format, the file gets corrupted.  Here is my code:

```
Public Sub DLFile(FName As String)
    Dim URI = _Host & "/" & _RemoteDir & "/" & FName
    Dim Dest = _LocalDir & "\V7`0_" & FName

    _Response = FTP_Transact(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile, URI)
    Using reader = New StreamReader(_Response.GetResponseStream)
        Using writer = New StreamWriter(Dest, append:=False)
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd())
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function FTP_Transact(What As String, URI As String) As System.Net.FtpWebResponse
    _Request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(URI), FtpWebRequest)
    _Request.Method = What
    _Request.UseBinary =True
    _Request.Credentials = _Credentials
    FTP_Transact = DirectCast(_Request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
End Function
```

I realize that it is using Ascii transfer not Binary but I don't see how I can change that.  StreamReader and StreamWriter need to be replaced by what??

**UPDATE: MINOR CHANGE FIXES THE PROBLEM**
@Eser nailed it!  The finished code looks like this:

```
Public Sub DLFile(FName As String)
    Dim URI = _Host & "/" & _RemoteDir & "/" & FName
    Dim Dest = _LocalDir & "\V7`0_" & FName

    _Response = FTP_Transact(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile, URI)
    If File.Exists(Dest) Then File.Delete(Dest)
    Using writer = New FileStream(Dest, FileMode.Create)
        _Response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(writer)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: StreamReader/[StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) is for reading/writing *text* to a stream. use FileStream

Comment: @Eser Could you please elaborate?  What would the code look like?  The FileStream for reading would need to access the .gz file on the FTP server.  I don't see how that would be done.  There are likely more steps than I am aware of.  It does not appear to be a simple swap of the methods.

Comment: in c#, something like `_Response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(yourFileStreamToWrite)` That is all

Comment: @Eser Yes, it works just fine.  Thanks to very much.  And it is so elegant!